# Regression in high dimensions ($p>n$) with nonnegative outcome

Tags: r, regression, data-transformation, lasso, high-dimensional

I need to perform regression in a setting where my outcome is positive ($Y > 0$) and there are more variables than rows ($p > n$). The goal of the analysis is to obtain predictions, which, of course, must be nonnegative.

Would it be as simple as performing LASSO (or other regularization) on the log-transformed outcome (e.g. $log(Y)$ regressed on $X$), and then exponentiating the predictions? Is this valid, or are there more complexities in obtaining that prediction that I have ignored here?

It would also be helpful to know if there are possibly better ideas that generally work for high-dimensional data with nonnegative outcome (e.g. a transformed version of random forests that works for positive outcome?). Thank you!

---

Update: I've read in certain places that if you take log(outcome) and want a mean prediction back on the original scale, you can't just exponentiate the mean on the log scale. However, I don't follow this, nor do I understand how to fix the issue (in the LASSO case, but also generally, with any type of model).

---

Additional details: The reason for the positive outcome is that I am trying to perform a residual reweighting (because of heteroscedasticity), in which the **denominator of the weights are the expected squared residuals**. To obtain the expected squared residuals, I am regressing the true squared residuals on $X$ - hence the strictly positive outcome. In my question above, $Y$ directly refers to these observed squared residuals. I want it to be clear, though, that this explanation is secondary to my question. My primary goal is that I want to model $Y \sim X$ properly, given the nonnegative outcome and high dimensonality.

Comment: can you give more details about Y? and your general problem? i suspect there a lot of possible options.  log Y is implying your effects are multiplicative not additive which may or may not be appropriate

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @seanv507. I've added more details to the question now!

Comment: For modeling heteroscedasticity, look into [gamlss](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=gamlss+answers%3A1)